# C3.js grouping issue

Tags: stack, grouping, c3.js

I'm building a C3.js application which monitors network traffic. Unfortunately my data points are spread all over the timeline and data for different groups may be present at different times. To complicate the issue, some data sets contain more data points than others. To give a better idea using an example, consider the data below:

```
c3.data.columns = [
    [
        "10.31.144.30->192.168.100.17:443 (1374.61 KB)",
        6600,
        34900
    ],
    [
        "10.31.144.35->192.168.100.1:443 (1333.4 KB)",
        8500,
        1900,
        6500,
        12700
    ],
    [
        "10.31.144.32->192.168.100.19:80 (710.45 KB)",
        18500
    ],
    [
        "10.31.144.30->192.168.100.14:80 (774.56 KB)",
        10836,
        10272
    ],
    [
        "10.31.144.33->192.168.100.2:443 (642.87 KB)",
        13900
    ]
]
```

The data above draws fine till I start to group it with the below parameter:

```
c3.data.groups = [[
    "10.31.144.30->192.168.100.17:443 (1374.61 KB)",
    "10.31.144.35->192.168.100.1:443 (1333.4 KB)",
    "10.31.144.32->192.168.100.19:80 (710.45 KB)",
    "10.31.144.30->192.168.100.14:80 (774.56 KB)",
    "10.31.144.33->192.168.100.2:443 (642.87 KB)"
]]
```

Does anybody know why grouping in my case isn't working? Its throwing a JS error in the function below:

```
c3_chart_internal_fn.getShapeOffset = function (typeFilter, indices, isSub) {
        var $$ = this,
            targets = $$.orderTargets($$.filterTargetsToShow($$.data.targets.filter(typeFilter, $$))),
            targetIds = targets.map(function (t) { return t.id; });
        return function (d, i) {
            var scale = isSub ? $$.getSubYScale(d.id) : $$.getYScale(d.id),
                y0 = scale(0), offset = y0;
            targets.forEach(function (t) {
                var values = $$.isStepType(d) ? $$.convertValuesToStep(t.values) : t.values;
                if (t.id === d.id || indices[t.id] !== indices[d.id]) { return; }
                if (targetIds.indexOf(t.id) < targetIds.indexOf(d.id)) {
                    if (values[i].value * d.value >= 0) {
                        offset += scale(values[i].value) - y0;
                    }
                }
            });
            return offset;
        };
    };
```